# Understanding downloaded file location in php

Tags: php, file, security

I have this code in `download.php` file:

```
$file = //path to file (for example .xlsx file)
if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xlsx');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
```

So, if open `site.com/download.php`, excel file is downloaded.

My question is:

**somehow, downloader can understand  what is a downloaded xlsx file location on the server? or this is impossible?**

Comment: the client cannot know, and does not NEED to know where/how the server actually provided the file. For all you know, the server's owner could have an army of underpaid slaves typing in files from paper copies whenever they're requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The client will have no idea where on the server the excel file came from.

You could be generating it in realtime or scraping it from another site or loading from a file. No way to tell.